# Admin Dashboard - Add JavaScript

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, javascript, admin-panel

I have a problem for add a simple JavaScript on my admin dashboard.

I have create a local.xml with my folder theme but no result.

**www\app\design\adminhtml\mytheme\default\layout\local.xml**

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>mytheme/jquery.js</script></action>      
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your custom admin theme applied? If so, did you get any 404 error for **mytheme/jquery.js**?

Comment: did you set theme for admin?

Comment: I have set my theme here: Design\Package\Current Package Name

Comment: That is for setting the frontend theme. There is no backend option for setting a backend theme in Magento so far.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to build a separate admin theme for that. 
Just place your local.xml under this location:

**\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\local.xml**